# Type mismatch error between Joda DateTime and sql Timestamp in Slick GetResult

Tags: scala, jodatime, playframework-2.1, slick

I want to retrieve data of a column with type DateTime and I am using jodatime for it. Even though I have a custom TypeMapper, I am getting type mismatch error.

```
[error] C:\sample\modules\test\com\samp\user.scala:55: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : java.sql.Timestamp
[error]  required: org.joda.time.DateTime
[error]             result.nextTimestamp,
[error]                    ^
[error] one error found
```

Here is the code

```
import org.specs2.mutable.Specification
import scala.slick.session.Database
import Database.threadLocalSession
import scala.slick.jdbc.{GetResult, StaticQuery => Q}
import Q.interpolation
import org.joda.time.DateTime
import scala.slick.lifted.{MappedTypeMapper,TypeMapper}
import java.sql.Timestamp

class UserSpec
  extends Specification {

  "User tests " should {
    "get all the user data in db" in
      new WithServer() {

      val db = Database.forURL(url = "jdbc:h2:/path/to/db-file", driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")

      implicit def dateTimeTypeMapper = MappedTypeMapper.base[DateTime, Timestamp] (
        dateTime => new Timestamp(dateTime.getMillis()),
        timeStamp => new DateTime(timeStamp)
      )

      case class user(
        id: String,
        name: String,
        joinedAt: DateTime,
        description: Option[String]
      )

      implicit val getUserResult: GetResult[user] = 
        GetResult( result =>
         user(
           result.nextString,
           result.nextString,
           result.nextTimestamp,
           result.nextStringOption)
      )

      db withSession {
        val usr = Q.queryNA[user]("SELECT * FROM user").list()
        usr foreach println
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am not sure why this is not working. Any help or pointers is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that `result.nextTimestamp` returns a `java.sql.Timestamp` (`result` is the JDBC `ResultSet`). If you want to turn it into a `DateTime`, I think that there's a constructor for it. So you'd write:

```
implicit val getUserResult: GetResult[user] = 
  GetResult( result =>
    user(
      result.nextString,
      result.nextString,
      new DateTime(result.nextTimestamp),
      result.nextStringOption)
    )
```

Comment: Correct. A MappedTypeMapper tells Slick how to do the conversion for the type-safe query api. That's not what is needed here.

Comment: This helped me get rid of compilation error but now I am seeing a runtime exception `JdbcSQLException: Cannot parse "TIMESTAMP" constant "1" [22007-168] (DbException.java:158)`. Any suggestions?

Comment: It's hard to say anything about this without knowing what the data and the table looks like. Most likely you're selecting `*` which contains more columns than the mapping, or in a different order - I'd suggest an explicit query such as `SELECT id, name, joinedAt, description FROM user`